# Can not decrypt encrypted S/MIME message

Tags: thunderbird, exchange, apple-mail, smime

After I sent an S/MIME signed eMail to an insurance company, their exchange server picked up my S/MIME certificate and their reply was S/MIME encrypted. Before, they used my PGP public key to encrypt messages sent to me, which I was able to decrypt. They never signed their own messages.

Despite the certificate and the private S/MIME key are installed in Thunderbird and Apple Mail, none of them are able to decrypt the message. (*Thunderbird can't decrypt message. The sender used one of your certificates to encrypt this message. Despite that, Thunderbird couldn't find the certificate and the matching private key.*)

Messages I receive from other entities using my S/MIME certificate for encryption can be decrypted by Thunderbird and Apple Mail, including self-sent test messages and messages from swiftmail/PHP.

The private key is not on a smart card but stored in Thunderbird's software security module and Apple's keychain.

Here are some of the mail headers of the unencryptable eMail I received from the insurance company:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=smime.p7m
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; name=smime.p7m; 
 smime-type="enveloped-data"
...
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
x-ms-exchange-transport-fromentityheader: Hosted
...
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Decryption by hand as suggested in [How to decrypt a broken S/MIME message sent by Outlook?](https://superuser.com/questions/1135192/how-to-decrypt-a-broken-s-mime-message-sent-by-outlook) also fails:

```
$ openssl smime -decrypt -in msg.eml  -inkey privatekey.pem  -out decrypted.txt
Error decrypting PKCS#7 structure
140735747326920:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:529:
```

How to find what's wrong on whose end?

Edit:

```
$ openssl smime -pk7out -in msg.eml | openssl asn1parse
    0:d=0  hl=4 l=27205 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-envelopedData
   15:d=1  hl=4 l=27190 cons: cont [ 0 ]        
   19:d=2  hl=4 l=27186 cons: SEQUENCE          
   23:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
   26:d=3  hl=4 l= 457 cons: SET               
   30:d=4  hl=4 l= 453 cons: SEQUENCE          
   34:d=5  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
   37:d=5  hl=3 l= 172 cons: SEQUENCE          
   40:d=6  hl=3 l= 151 cons: SEQUENCE          
   43:d=7  hl=2 l=  11 cons: SET               
   45:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE          
   47:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :countryName
   52:d=9  hl=2 l=   2 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :GB
   56:d=7  hl=2 l=  27 cons: SET               
   58:d=8  hl=2 l=  25 cons: SEQUENCE          
   60:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :stateOrProvinceName
   65:d=9  hl=2 l=  18 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :Greater Manchester
   85:d=7  hl=2 l=  16 cons: SET               
   87:d=8  hl=2 l=  14 cons: SEQUENCE          
   89:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :localityName
   94:d=9  hl=2 l=   7 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :Salford
  103:d=7  hl=2 l=  26 cons: SET               
  105:d=8  hl=2 l=  24 cons: SEQUENCE          
  107:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :organizationName
  112:d=9  hl=2 l=  17 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :COMODO CA Limited
  131:d=7  hl=2 l=  61 cons: SET               
  133:d=8  hl=2 l=  59 cons: SEQUENCE          
  135:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
  140:d=9  hl=2 l=  52 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :COMODO RSA Client Authentication and Secure Email CA
  194:d=6  hl=2 l=  16 prim: INTEGER           :7F9285XXXX...
  212:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
  214:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaesOaep
  225:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 cons: SEQUENCE          
  227:d=5  hl=4 l= 256 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:0068E5XXXX...
  487:d=3  hl=4 l=26718 cons: SEQUENCE          
  491:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-data
  502:d=4  hl=2 l=  29 cons: SEQUENCE          
  504:d=5  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :aes-256-cbc
  515:d=5  hl=2 l=  16 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:CF1A61XXXX...
  533:d=4  hl=4 l=26672 prim: cont [ 0 ]
```

Comment: Maybe [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304570/how-to-resolve-the-evp-decryptfinal-ex-bad-decrypt-during-file-decryption) could be helpful. [One comment suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39641378/284111) to specify the algorithm. The sender might use a deprecated algorithm. Try `openssl smime -pk7out -in msg.eml | openssl asn1parse` on the email to analyze it and display the algorithm used without attempting to decrypt it.

Comment: Btw, I'm using a slightly different command to decrypt emails: `openssl smime -decrypt -in msg.eml -recip recipient.pem`, but I have no idea if that could make a difference in your case.

Comment: My openssl (`LibreSSL 2.2.7`) tells me `-recip  file   recipient certificate file for decryption`. From what I understand you always need a private key for decryption, which is not part of the certificate (because the certificate can be publicly shared). What exactly is inside your `recipient.pem`?

Comment: @not2savvy thanks for the asn parse commands. When I analyze a message sent by my clients to myself, I see `des-EDE3-CBC` is used and there 2 entries in the SET starting at offset 26, both using the same `commonName`. Not sure, yet how to use `openssl aes-128-cbc`/ how to specify the message digest algo. Using `-md` with `openssl smime` didn't change anything.

Comment: The `recipient.pem` must of course contain the private key to decrypt the email.

Comment: The term certificate is not limited to be used for public certificates only, so don't get irritated by that. A pem file can contain both private as well as public keys.